# After I install a theme it should say Recommended Plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am learning WordPress theme development and now I need to know a feature how can I add the option on my theme so my client after install the theme he can get a notification that you need to install following recommanded plugin.
How can I do that? I need it as early as possible.
Waiting for your response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't have this feature implemented yet. But you can use external libraries.

Currently, the most used is [TGM Plugin Activator](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/).

You can configure required and recommended plugins.

On the TGMPA site, you can found an tutorial of how use it.